# Javascript clickableGrid

Tags: javascript

Hi i am using this code

http://jsfiddle.net/6qkdP/2/

CSS code:

```
.grid { margin:1em auto; border-collapse:collapse }
.grid td {
cursor:pointer;
width:30px; height:30px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
text-align:center;
font-family:sans-serif; font-size:13px
}
.grid td.clicked {
background-color:yellow;
font-weight:bold; color:red;
}
```

javascript code:

```
var lastClicked;
var grid = clickableGrid(10,10,function(el,row,col,i){
console.log("You clicked on element:",el);
console.log("You clicked on row:",row);
console.log("You clicked on col:",col);
console.log("You clicked on item #:",i);

el.className='clicked';
if (lastClicked) lastClicked.className='';
lastClicked = el;
});

document.body.appendChild(grid);

function clickableGrid( rows, cols, callback ){
var i=0;
var grid = document.createElement('table');
grid.className = 'grid';
for (var r=0;r<rows;++r){
    var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    for (var c=0;c<cols;++c){
        var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        cell.innerHTML = ++i;
        cell.addEventListener('click',(function(el,r,c,i){
            return function(){
                callback(el,r,c,i);
            }
        })(cell,r,c,i),false);
    }
}
return grid;
}
```

I am new to javascript, I need when I run the code, I draw another cell for example if I execute the code, how do I do it if I want the cell to be drawn with the number 25?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Draw the number 25 where?

Comment: is a example , i want manipulate the coordenates of the matrix

Comment: Manipulate in what way? Your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: The code generates a panel when you click on the position, the position change the color , i need save some positions in a txt and when i run the code this positions changed the color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a new fiddle to show you how it's done. I created a `<div>` and when an element is clicked, it appends the number that was clicked to the div in a paragraph tag. Notice the changes in your grid callback.

```
<div id="numSelected">
<p>
Numbers selected are below:
</p>
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var lastClicked;
var grid = clickableGrid(11,11,function(el,row,col,i){
    console.log("You clicked on element:",el);
    console.log("You clicked on row:",row);
    console.log("You clicked on col:",col);
    console.log("You clicked on item #:",i);

    el.className='clicked';
    if (lastClicked) lastClicked.className='';
    lastClicked = el;

    var div = document.createElement('p');
    div.innerHTML = i;

    document.getElementById('numSelected').appendChild(div);
});

document.body.appendChild(grid);

function clickableGrid( rows, cols, callback ){
    var i=0;
    var grid = document.createElement('table');
    grid.className = 'grid';
    for (var r=0;r<rows;++r){
        var tr = grid.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        for (var c=0;c<cols;++c){
            var cell = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            cell.innerHTML = ++i;
            cell.addEventListener('click',(function(el,r,c,i){
                return function(){
                    callback(el,r,c,i);
                }
            })(cell,r,c,i),false);
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/difster/s9pka2ps/)

Comment: thanks!
I want to change the color of the cell with the number 25 when I click on another position

Comment: I updated the fiddle. Check it out. I added another css class so the previously clicked number is black with a red background.

Comment: If I want the cell with the number 1 is by default green, how do I do?

Comment: You didn't write this grid system yourself did you? You have no idea what to do with it? If you even had a basic understanding of what was in the fiddle you posted, you'd know how to change it.

Comment: it is not my code , only i want how to do that for my project and this is my first program in js

Comment: You don't want to know how to do it, you want someone to do it for you. I'll let you figure out the rest.

Comment: just i want how to changue de color of the cell by default, that the post idea, your "solutions"  are not hepful

Comment: Look at the css in the fiddle I linked. It's easy to figure out.

Comment: yes, just help me with that , thanks for patience but i am new in web

Comment: I'll tell you what. Mark the answer as solved and give it an upvote and then I'll solve the color problem.

Comment: You want the background of whatever is currently clicked to be green or the previously clicked backgrounds to be green?

Comment: no , just i want that the cell with the number 1 the brackground change to green, when i run the code i can see the cell with the number 1 in green

Comment: Here you go. But it will change color if clicked after the grid is built. http://jsfiddle.net/difster/s9pka2ps/4/